# How to run swagger yaml file locally

Tags: yaml, swagger, documentation, swagger-ui

How can I run swagger files locally on windows ?
I know we can try it on https://editor.swagger.io/ but I am splitting swagger file into multiples files so I wanted to know how to run it on windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "run swagger files locally"? Do you want to run the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io) locally? Or run [Swagger UI](https://petstore.swagger.io) documentation renderer locally? Something else?

Comment: I am new to this so sorry if I wrote something wrong. I already have a written swagger file with 5k lines of code and I have to split it into multiple files. After splitting I would like to see the output, now since there will be multiple files I don't think I can run it online, hence I wanted to see the output locally on my windows machine

Answer (score 1):

To render your own swagger files on windows, you can clone the repository on github and change the contents of index.html in the dist folder to point to the local path to your swagger file. When rendering multiple files at once, you can use the dropdown component to render each file based on your selection. That can be done in the "urls" parameter inside of the onload function in index.html. Then, you can run the app using npm start.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31135652)